# R - Delete stops words in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, corpus, stop-words

I am working with text analytics. I needed to count sentences. My code is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
txt <- readLines("consolidado.txt",encoding="UTF-8")
txt = iconv(txt, to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
text_df <- data_frame(line = 1:392, text = txt)
palabras1 <- text_df %>%   unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 1)
palabras2 <- text_df %>%   unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 2)
palabras3 <- text_df %>%   unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 3)
palabras4 <- text_df %>%   unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 4)
palabras5 <- text_df %>%   unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 5)
palabras6 <- text_df %>%   unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 6)
palabras7 <- text_df %>%   unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 7)
```

First I convert the txt in a dataframe and later I work with tidytext. This work nice, but the problem is the stop words. I want to delete the stops word in the dataframe but I dont know how. I tried to convert it in a corpus, but in this way don´t work because although it eliminates the stops words later it can´t count the sentences.

is there some way for deleting the stop words in a dataframe???

thank you

Comment: Do an `anti_join` with `stop_words`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with anti_join... but i get this error:

```
by required, because the data sources have no common variables
```

Googling about this problem I tried with:

```
by = NULL
by = c("a" = "b")
by = c(namecolumn = namecolumn)
```

and many ways more with "by", but I didn´t get it.

Finally I got it with this solution:

```
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

txt <- readLines("consolidado.txt",encoding="UTF-8")
txt = iconv(txt, to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
text_df <- data_frame(line = 1:392, text = txt)

text_df$text = removeWords(text_df$text, stopwords("spanish"))
text_df$text = stripWhitespace(text_df$text)
```

The library tm has the spanish stopwords.

I select the column with the text in my dataframe, by default this column is called text. Later I use the function removeWords to erase the stopwords. The last line is to delete double whitespaces after to delete stopwords.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Most text mining packages in `R` contain standardized functions for removing common stop words. In the `tidytext` package, the authors include a `stop_words` data set containing common stop words. Something like this should do the trick:

```
text_df <- data_frame(line = 1:392, text = txt) %>%
                      txt_df %>%
                      anti_join(stop_words)
```